# findViewById - Nested LinearLayouts, doesn't locate my id's - Android

Tags: android

I've scoured the internet to no avail. I'm trying to set the font for a textview. It's in its own LinearLayout in my main.xml file. When I write the code in OnCreate, it doesn't locate the id, or the parent linearlayout. Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_message_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/map_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/diagram" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And the following onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.map_message_layout)
    TextView maptxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.map_message);
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/MuseoSans_100.otf");
    maptxt.setTypeface(typeFace);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it compile? I see you're missing a `</LinearLayout>` but I assure you just didn't copy that.

Comment: have you accidentally imported `android.R` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning your program? I had some odd stuff happen before and that fixed my issues. Not sure if that is in this case.

Comment: I was actually in the wrong java file o_O. I'm still not a fan of Eclipse after XCode. whoops. I also had to clean up the code a bit, but I got it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: lol, I have done that too a few timers here or there. I don't mind eclipse but I could see room for improvement in a few areas I guess. Overall though I don't mind it.